# Average a list of matrix

Tags: r, matrix

For example, I have a list of matrix like this

```
list2<-lapply(1:2, function(x) matrix(rnorm(6, 10, 1), nrow=2, ncol=3))
list2
```

How do I get a matrix which has the same size with each matrix in each list, and the value in each cell equal to the average of corresponding cell across lists.

Answer (score 0):

We can do this by adding the corresponding cells in each `list` elements and divide by the `length` of the `list`

```
Reduce(`+`, list2)/length(list2)
```

---

Or another option is to `unlist` the `list`, create a 3D `array`, use `apply` to get the `mean`

```
apply(array(unlist(list2), c(2,3,2)), c(1,2), mean)
```